# Uses of [◯]{まる} symbol in Japanese typography

Tags: usage, kanji, symbols

What is [◯]{まる} symbol is typically used for?

The only usage I know of is the "correct" mark. But the dictionary says it is also used as a placeholder and for censorship, see [◯](http://jisho.org/word/%E2%97%8B) and [◯◯](http://jisho.org/search/%E3%80%87%E3%80%87%20%E3%81%BE%E3%82%8B%E3%81%BE%E3%82%8B).

Here are more detailed questions:

1. Are there any other uses?
2. Where can I typically see those?
3. Can it be used in grammar/spelling tests as a "fill the blank" for kanji?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I usually see ○○ when people refer to a series of related things with similar names. For example, here is an [article](http://dic.nicovideo.jp/a/%E5%8D%B1%E9%99%BA%E3%81%AA%E2%97%8B%E2%97%8B%E3%82%B7%E3%83%AA%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BA) about 危険な○○シリーズ, which is a series of comical video remixes that use the same song and are typically called 危険な[something].

Also on the Internet it can be used for self-censorship (often comical I think), like ち◯こ instead of ちんこ.

I've also (rarely) seen people using ●● instead, not sure if there is a difference.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen it a lot on television shows to represent "something", probably like your placeholder you mentioned and also as censorship for words on the subtitle-like [テロップ](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%B9%E3%83%BC%E3%83%91%E3%83%BC%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%83%9D%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BA_(%E6%98%A0%E5%83%8F%E7%B7%A8%E9%9B%86)).

e.g. `１００人に聞いた[この夏、◯◯をしたい！！]　TOP3ランキング！！！`

e.g. `う◯こ`